# Critical exponents from Ising free energy at zero magnetic field?

Tags: ising-model, partition-function, critical-phenomena

Consider the free energy of an Ising model $f(J,h,T)$, where $J$ is the coupling between neighboring sites, $h$ is the magnitude of a homogeneous external magnetic field and $T$ is the temperature.

Assume that we know the quantity $f(J,0,T)$ exactly, where the external magnetic field is set to zero.

From the above knowledge, we can easily calculate the specific heat $C=-T^2\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial T^2}$, and obtain the critical exponent $\alpha$ from its behavior around the critical temperature $T_c$.

By the scaling relation $\nu d = 2-\alpha$, this would also provide us with the critical exponent $\nu$ within the correlation length $\xi$.

My question is, knowing only $f(J,0,T)$, are there any further critical exponents we can obtain?